# Helm template not rendering correct condition

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have to 2 different values in my helm chart and a combination of them decided whether a file is generated or not. The 2 values are

```
cluster: test
networkpolicy: true
```

I need to generate a NetworkPolicy based on 4 different cases.

```
Case          |  1   |   2   |  3   |  4 
--------------------------------------------
cluster       | test | test  | prod | prod
networkpolicy | true | false | true | false
--------------------------------------------
Outcome       | true | false | true | fail
```

The above table shows the out come I want. Here is my code in `_helpers.tpl` file

```
{{- define "jenkins.networkpolicy" -}}
{{- if eq .Values.cluster "prod" -}}
  {{- if .Values.networkpolicy -}}
    {{- "true" -}}
  {{- else -}}
    {{- fail "Network policy cannot be disabled in prod" -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- else -}}
  {{- if .Values.networkpolicy -}}
    {{- "true" -}}
  {{- else -}}
    {{- "false" -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

{{- end -}}
```

and im calling it in my `networkpolicy.yaml` file like this

```
{{- if (include "jenkins.networkpolicy" .) }}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
.
.
{{- end }}
```

The above code works fine for 3 out of 4 cases. Case #2 does not work. It should not be templating/ignoring the file but it still generates it. Any idea what I am missing here ?

```
✗ helm template . -f ./values.yaml --set environment.id=test --set cluster=test --set networkpolicy=false | head -10
---
# Source: jkmaster-networkpolicy.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-jkmaster-networkpolicy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-jkmaster # label of pod to isolate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your helper functions returns a non empty string with either `"true"` or `"false"` value

Look at the [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#ifelse) when `if` statement is evaluated as false

> A pipeline is evaluated as false if the value is:
>
> - a boolean false
> - a numeric zero
> - an empty string
> - a nil (empty or null)
>   an empty collection (map, slice, tuple, dict, array)

A string `"false"` is evaluated as boolean `true`

Replacing `"false"` with empty string `""` makes your code working as expected

```
{{- define "jenkins.networkpolicy" -}}
{{- if eq .Values.cluster "prod" -}}
  {{- if .Values.networkpolicy -}}
    {{- "true" -}}
  {{- else -}}
    {{- fail "Network policy cannot be disabled in prod" -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- else -}}
  {{- if .Values.networkpolicy -}}
    {{- "true" -}}
  {{- else -}}
    {{- "" -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

{{- end -}}
```

Comment: I am facing same issue @Yuri G. can you pls have a look at my question